# Link to document outside the web root

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been looking for hours for an answer to this question and although there are hundreds of posts on it, I can't find an answer specifically to my problem...

I have created a site where people can download zip files of barcode packages. Initially i created the site with a customers/codes folder in the web root. I was creating the zip files with this:

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/speedy/customers/codes/'
```

Which outputs `'/var/www/html/speedy/customers/codes/'`

After finishing the site my client has decided that he doesn't want anyone but the logged in user to be able to access their file. So I figured that the easiest way with the least amount of major system changes would be to move the customers/codes folder OUTSIDE of the web root.

So i made the file in /var/www/customers/codes

How can I link to these files outside the web root? I've tried a few things and nothing worked. I tried this...

```
'../../'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/customers/codes/';
```

... but it actually echos out the "../".

Here is the portion of my code that generates the zip file. I need to link to /var/www/customers/codes

```
system('/usr/bin/zip -j ' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/speedy/customers/codes/'.$order_id.'.zip ' . escapeshellarg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/speedy/certificates/'.$order_id.'-certificate.pdf'));
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the directory password protected using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the path just as it appears on your filesystem. In your case:

```
system('/usr/bin/zip -j ' . '/var/www/customers/codes/'.$order_id.'.zip ' . escapeshellarg($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/speedy/certificates/'.$order_id.'-certificate.pdf'));
```

Comment: Ok, almost there, my only other question is, how would I link to this file from the client side account? I can't do href="/var/www/customers/codes/68454354.zip'

Comment: You would need to create a php script which retrieves the contents of the file and outputs it: href="getCodeZip.php?code=68454354".

Comment: Thanks you put me on the right track. I just left the customers/codes directory in the webroot and blocked all access with an htaccess file. Then I made it where the script encrypts the order id and sends it to a function that decrypts the order id and serves them the file. Thanks!